# Windows was unable to communicate with the target application. Extremely annoying error

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a huge problem here at the moment. It happens to me when I try to bind to dictionaries, do reflection or like in this case use transitions.

When I try to start the app I get the following error:

Unable to activate Windows Store app [App-Name here]. The activation request failedith error 'Windows was unable to communicate with the target application. This usually indicates that the target application's process aborted. More information may be available in the Debug pane of the Output windows (Debug->Windows->Output).

See help for advice on troubleshooting the issue.

The Output windows does not offer any further information regarding the issue. In fact it even says that the app launched properly.

I have already checked like every blog or forums-entry on the internet but nothing seems to help. I have reinstalled my VS 2012 and the error still occurs. In this case, the following code causes the error (regardless of which transition I use on what element)

```
       <StackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
            <PopupThemeTransition/>
       </StackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
```

I am REALLY out of ideas. In another case the following code caused that crash:

```
public class PresentColorsView 
{
    static PresentColorsView ()
    {
        List<PresentColorsView> ColorsList = new List<PresentColorsView>();
        IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> Properties = typeof(Colors).GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties;

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in Properties)
        {
            PresentColorsView tmpAddColors = new PresentColorsView();

            if (property.Name.Length < 7)
            {
                tmpAddColors.ColorName = property.Name;
                tmpAddColors.Color = (Color) property.GetValue(null);
                ColorsList.Add(tmpAddColors);
            }
        }

        AllColors = ColorsList;
    }

    public string ColorName { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public static IEnumerable<PresentColorsView> AllColors { get; set; }
}
```

I am really out of ideas and don't know what to do anymore. I frequently get this error on stuff I even have copied exactly word or word from a book or something. This is limiting my developing abilities on a high scale!

I really appreciate every piece of advice. I am thinking about downloading VS 2013 and check weather the bug will still occur.

Thank you very much!

Greetings, FunkyPeanut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your code throws an unhandled exception. You should handle exceptions *at least* in the `Main` method, log them or otherwise let yourself know something went wrong.

In the particular piece of code this line is most likely causing the issue:

```
tmpAddColors.Color = (Color) property.GetValue(null);
```

If you [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you'd quickly figure out it says “Returns the property value of a **specified object**.” The important part being **bold**. You are passing a `null`. Hence either `GetValue` fails immediately, throwing an exception, or the cast to `Color` throws an `InvalidCastException` (in case `Color` is a value type).

Comment: Makes sense! I will check for that later! Thank you. The Transition thing was solved by installing vs 2013 - I don't know why but everything works fine now!

Answer (score 0):

I just have got the same error when trying to debug a WPhone App.

Spite of my issue is not related whit this one, and after long time reading threads and trying eveything related with it, i have found where the problem is and I would like to share it.

I had a Dictionary instantiation at main class App.cs. When performing test phases I didn't realized that I have added a duplicate key and this simply raised the error reported on this post.